# Handle input and Firebase errors in MVVM architecture

Tags: java, android, firebase, mvvm, error-handling

I come from web development so my mobile development with Java isn't on the right track yet.
I am currently developing an android app using Firebase, for university and I am trying to use clean architecture, and as everything new to me I am coming across some issues.

I'm looking for information on how to handle errors from input in MVVM architecture.
For example, say I am trying to login to Firebase using email and password, the `View`gets the input text and calls the `AuthViewModel` method `signInWithEmail(String email, String password)`, which calls the `AuthRepository` method `firebaseSignInWithEmail()`.

## Code

#### SignInFragment

```
private void signInWithEmail() {
     String emailInput = binding.inputEmail.getText().toString();
     String passwordInput = binding.inputPassword.getText().toString();
     authViewModel.signInWithEmail(emailInput, passwordInput);
     authViewModel.authenticatedUserLiveData.observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), authenticatedUser ->{
         if(authenticatedUser != null){
             goToHome();
         }
     });
}
```

#### AuthViewModel

```
public LiveData<User> authenticatedUserLiveData;

public void signInWithEmail(String email, String password){
    authenticatedUserLiveData = authRepository.firebaseSignInWithEmail(email, password);
}
```

#### AuthRepository

```
public MutableLiveData<User> firebaseSignInWithEmail(String email, String password) {
        MutableLiveData<User> authenticatedUserMutableLiveData = new MutableLiveData<>();
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(authTask -> {
                    if(authTask.isSuccessful()){
                        FirebaseUser firebaseUser = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    if (firebaseUser != null) {
                        String uid = firebaseUser.getUid();
                        String name = firebaseUser.getDisplayName();
                        String firebaseUserEmail = firebaseUser.getEmail();
                        User user = new User(uid, name, firebaseUserEmail);
                        authenticatedUserMutableLiveData.setValue(user);
                   }
                } else {
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", authTask.getException());
                }
            });
    return authenticatedUserMutableLiveData;
}
```

## What I am trying to accomplish

The "correct" way of getting the `ApiException` from the `AuthRepository`, whcih is currently only being logged,

```
Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", authTask.getException());
```

and passing it to my `AuthViewModel` to display the error on a `TextView`, and not to enter the `goToHome()`.

## What I am thinking

I know viewmodel should only act as intermidiary and never have much logic of it's own.
My first taught was to check if the returned `MutableLiveData` from the repository method was null, but that left me without the ApiException since the `LiveData` is of type `User`, so I cannot return the ApiExcepiton.

Comment: Simply emit an object that contains either success or failure states. You can use the pattern described in the documentation:  https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/guide#addendum

Comment: If you are interested in a clean Firebase authentication with Google, you can check this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-clean-firebase-authentication-using-mvvm-37f9b8eb7336).

Answer (score 0):

Like what Doug mentioned as a comment, you should instead return a `Result` class from your repository. This is very easy in Kotlin.. but requires more work in Java.

First, create an abstract class `Result`, with two subclasses, `Success` and `Error`.

```
abstract class Result {}
class Success extends Result {
    private User mUser; // getters/setters omitted for brevity
    public Success(User user) { mUser = user }
}
class Error extends Result {
    private Error mError; // getters/setters omitted for brevity
    public Error(Error error) { mError = error }
}
```

You can include more details in these classes to better understand what went wrong, but I'm keeping things simple.

Then, in your ViewModel, you should have 2 LiveData values. One for a success, and one for an error. So your `AuthViewModel` will look like:

```
public LiveData<User> authenticatedUserLiveData;
public LiveData<Error> userSignInErrorLiveData;

public void signInWithEmail(String email, String password){
    Result result = authRepository.firebaseSignInWithEmail(email, password);
    if (result instanceof Success) {
        authenticatedUserLiveData.value = result.getUser();
    } else if (result instanceof Error) {
        userSignInErrorLiveData.value = result.getError();
    }
}
```

Finally, you just need to make your `AuthRepository` return a `Result`, so the signature will look like:

```
public Result firebaseSignInWithEmail(String email, String password)
```

And replace the line `authenticatedUserMutableLiveData.setValue(user);` with `return new Success(user);` and replace the logging line with `return new Error(authTask.getException);`

Hope this helps!

Comment: It gives me unexpected return value for `return new Error(authTask.getException())` and `return new Success(user)`

Comment: Did you change the signature to return a `Result` instead of a `MutableLiveData<User>`?

Comment: Yes I did change it

Comment: Out of the `addOnCompleteListener` it does not give me that error

Comment: I'm a bit confused by what you mean.. if what you mean is it cannot return from within the `addOnCompleteListener` but it does from outside of it, then you should create a local variable of type `Result`, set it inside in `onCompleteListener` and then return it at the end, just like you were doing previously with the LiveData